# How to run jenkins job with different parameters on different days?

Tags: jenkins, triggers

:)
I would like to share my problem and ask for help. 
Using an existing script I have to add separation of the launch by content dependency. 
Based on the info from the files, the script must read either the 'master' or 'track' argument. 
One part of Jenkins is run on Monday for the 'master' argument. I use: 
H H(0-5) * * 1

For the 'track' it will be launched on Wednesdays.

Here is my question:

- how to add the next run for the same jenkins but launched another day (separate for 'master' and 'track'?
- how I can add something like a splitter in the script for start the same JenkinsJob?

Comment: Just have multiple lines, one per condition. See this [answer in DevOps SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/11902/13379).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! 
But right now I"ve got problem with additional plugin in my Jenkins (I cant install it). 

I think about add new function in the bash script thanks to which it will be possible to check the day of the week.

On this basis the job will be properly executed:

    for master on Monday,
    for release tracks on Wednesday.
Could you please help with that?